# Error when defining a math operator and corresponding `\renewcommand`

Tags: macros, math-operators

I tried to define a new math operator - essentially a math macro. I wanted to define an operator for the Eccentricity of a graph or network. The code seems to work when I generate a PDF, however I am seeing some errors in the `.log` file.  Here is the actual code.

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Eccentricity}{\textbf{Ecc}\,}
\renewcommand{\ecc}[1]{\Eccentricity(#1)}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
! LaTeX Error: \ecc undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.153 \renewcommand{\ecc}
                         [1]{\Eccentricity(#1)}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

The message does not really indicate what the problem is. Can anyone suggest how to fix this error?

Comment: Why are you using `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`?

Comment: Oh I think I did that because I copied something from another snippet. If there is no pre-existing command, then does `\renewcommand` fail?

Comment: Yes it fails in that case.  Alternative: `\providecommand`

Comment: Okay great, that worked. I did not realize that little pitfall. Thanks for the quick response everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\renewcommand` checks whether the command is defined or not and generates an error if it's not defined. In this case, `\ecc` is not defined, so the message indicates *exactly* what the problem is.

You're most likely interested in `\newcommand`, which works for commands that have not been defined previously:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Eccentricity}{\mathbf{Ecc}}
\newcommand{\ecc}[1]{\Eccentricity(#1)}

\begin{document}

$\ecc{G}$

\end{document}
```

If needed, you can adjust the spacing around `\Ecc`. However, in general, there's no need for it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, when I changed from `\renewcommand`, to `\newcommand` this fixed the errors. Thanks so much.